# laravel 5 can't find mailjet class in the app folder

Tags: laravel-5, namespaces

I've started learning laravel and try to add mailjet to the RegisterController.php . I have a folder named Mailjet in the app folder with a file named Mailjet.php . This file contains this namespace at the beginning

```
namespace App\Mailjet;
```

in the RegisterController

```
use App\Mailjet\Mailjet;
```

But I get this error

```
FatalErrorException in RegisterController.php line 24: Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App\Mailjet\Mailjet' not found
```

While it should point to the mailjet folder in the app folder not in the auth folder. So how to fix this to access mailjet from the login, register controllers?

Answer (score 0):

The issue because i added

```
use App\Mailjet\Mailjet;
```

inside the class not before it. Sorry about this.